# Append a div to two separate divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

How can I append/prepend the same div created when the button is clicked to the divs in the HTML with the classes "quickAdds and "sideMenu, when the code completes it only prepends to sideMenu class div, I assume it overrides the quickAdds div because it's the last line of code. How can I fix this?

```js
var addTaskBtn = document.querySelector("#enterBtn");
var titleInput = document.querySelector("#textField");
var taskDescription = document.querySelector("#taskDescriptionBox");
var quickAdds = document.querySelector(".quickAdds");
var sideMenu = document.querySelector(".sideMenu");



addTaskBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var h = document.createElement("h2");
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  h.textContent = titleInput.value;
  p.textContent = taskDescription.value;
  div.appendChild(h);
  div.appendChild(p);
  quickAdds.prepend(div);
  sideMenu.prepend(div);
});
```

```css
.sideMenuContainer {
  /* display: none; */
  display: block;
  height: 100vw;
  width: 550px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #343434a4;
}

.sideMenu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  width: 550px;
  margin: 0;
}

.sideMenuTask {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.quickAdds {
  background: springgreen;
  height: auto;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -ms-border-radius: 3px;
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sideMenuContainer">
  <div class="sideMenu">

    <div class="sideMenuTask">
      <h1>heading of tasks</h1>
      <p>Body of tasks</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>




<div class="quickAdds">


</div>
```

Comment: you really should provide all your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tldr; you need to create two `div` elements.

When using [prepend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend) / [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) The **DOM will keep reference to the element, not value**.

This means that it running the following code:

```
quickAdds.prepend(div);
sideMenu.prepend(div);
```

Will do the following:

1. Prepend `div` to `quickAdds`
2. Detach `div` from `quickAdds`
3. Prepend `div` to `sideMenu`

In order to `prepend` to both, you need to create two `div` elements. E.g.

```
const div = document.createElement('div');
const div2 = document.createElement('div');
quickAdds.prepend(div);
sideMenu.prepend(div2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements are objects. When you create them they are unique, this is why when you move a node around like you are, it doesn't duplicate itself, the element node is actually *moved*.

We can use `object.assign` to duplicate an object, even an element, but the problem here is that you have several elements nested within each other. In order for them to be properly appended every single one of them has to be duplicated separately. When that's the case it's best to just create them individually or, more preferably, in a loop or function call.

When it comes to this type of situation I typically use functional programming to solve the problem, or at least mitigate the code.

This starts out with creating a simple `create` function that we can adjust for our needs.

```js
function create(ele, params = {}) {
return Object.assign(document.createElement(ele), params);
}

let h2;
console.log( h2 = create("h2", { className: "blue", textContent: "hiya!" } )); 

document.body.appendChild(h2);
```

```css
.blue {
background: blue;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
color: white;
}
```

You can extend this for use in your code. This is a simple example of how it could work, but you can also simplify this quite a great deal if you use the function properly. I won't go into that in depth because it's out of scope for this answer, but it's not difficult to imagine.

```js
var addTaskBtn = document.querySelector("#enterBtn");
var titleInput = document.querySelector("#textField");
var taskDescription = document.querySelector("#taskDescriptionBox");
var quickAdds = document.querySelector(".quickAdds");
var sideMenu = document.querySelector(".sideMenu");



addTaskBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var div = create("div"), div2 = create("div");
  
  var h = create("h2", { textContent: titleInput.value }), 
  h2 = create("h2", { textContent: titleInput.value });
  
  var p = create("p", {textContent: taskDescription.value }), 
  p2 = create("p", {textContent: taskDescription.value });
  

  div.appendChild(h); div2.appendChild(h2);
  div.appendChild(p); div2.appendChild(p2);
  
  quickAdds.prepend(div);
  sideMenu.prepend(div2);
});

function create(ele, params = {}) {
return Object.assign(document.createElement(ele), params);
}
```

```css
.sideMenuContainer {
  /* display: none; */
  display: block;
  height: 100vw;
  width: 550px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #343434a4;
}

.sideMenu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  width: 550px;
  margin: 0;
}

.sideMenuTask {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.quickAdds {
  background: springgreen;
  height: auto;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -ms-border-radius: 3px;
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sideMenuContainer">
  <div class="sideMenu">

    <div class="sideMenuTask">
      <h1>heading of tasks</h1>
      <p>Body of tasks</p>
    </div>
    <button id="enterBtn">add task or whatever</button>
  </div>
</div>




<div class="quickAdds">


</div>

<input type="text" id="textField">
<input type="text" id="titleInput" value="hihihhihi">
<input type="text" id="taskDescriptionBox" value="this is a description ">
```